# win32 what happens if app crashed/BSODed while running WriteFile having unbuffered and write_THROUGH flags on NTFS

Tags: winapi, io, writefile

i'm overwriting to file in 10mb chunks
by [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) API
handle is opened using
FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH |FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS
flags in [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)

my question is : what happens to the chunk if my app crashed/terminated/windows BSODed (i'm not asking about powerloss)
does the 10mb chuck get overwritten fully , not written at all or partly written ?

if filesystem  matters ,NTFS with features that are enabled by defualt in regular windows installation is my question

i'd like to know your experience or knowledge
thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the filesystem you're writing to. If you have journaling turned on etc. If you're on NTFS and you have journaling enabled then there is a chance that it would roll back. But it's just that... a chance. I would highly suggest you [read this for solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/deprecation-of-txf)

Comment: @Mgetz it's for ntfs, i'will edit the question to mention that , i think you can write your comment as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: So it would actually help more if we knew what you were trying to do. What NTFS does depends a lot on where your file is, if that folder has shadow copies turned on. Whether or not a write has completed. etc. This is why a common method of handling this is copy and swap. That way the original file is never corrupted.